# Is there any advantage to consuming lodash in a modular way if I am using uglify?

Tags: webpack, browserify, lodash, uglifyjs

In comments on [this performance audit of a React site](https://github.com/reddit/reddit-mobile/issues/247), the lodash author suggests "cherry-picking" methods in lodash (i.e., `require`ing individual methods instead of the whole lodash package) or using the [individual packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized).  But shouldn't this be unnecessary if using a dead code eliminator such as uglify or the closure compiler as part of the bundling process (using browserify or webpack)?

Comment: Who told you that webpack will drop unused lodash functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CommonJS style `require('lodash')`, Uglify doesn't dead code eliminate (I don't think Closure Compiler will be able to either).

However, if you are using ES6 style `import { merge, reduce } from 'lodash'` (for example), you will be able to take advantage of tree-shaking using Webpack2 (some other bundlers support it, too). Since ES6 module system has a static structure, the bundler can perform static analysis and determine that certain parts of library are not used and eliminate them.

For more information about tree-shaking with Webpack 2, you can take a look at http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html.

As of writing this answer (March 3, 2016), Webpack 2 is still in beta, so there may be some issues but if you'd like to experiment, give it a try!

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I misunderstood, but I'm kind of surprised.  I am pretty new to client-side JavaScript.  If I can't rely on some kind of dead code elimination, that seems terrible.  It means I will have to avoid using useful libraries if I only use a small part of them and that if I want to do "universal" JavaScript I have to be super careful not to pull in server code on the client. Really?  Also, I thought it wouldn't matter whether I used ES6 syntax since webpack statically analyzes CommonJS imports anyway.  Wow!

Comment: The difficulties with static analysis with CommonJS-style importing is that CommonJS style importing allows dynamic `require()`. What I mean by that is you can do things like `var prefix = "./test"; var num = Math.floor(Math.random(10) * 10); var module = require(prefix + num);`. You cannot reliably determine what gets loaded. Therefore, it's impossible to determine dead code. Whereas in ES6 module importing, such dynamic loading is not allowed. For example, you cannot do `import someModule from "./test" + num;` That's what I meant by ES6 module system having a static structure.

Comment: I get that, but Webpack already statically analyzes require statements using heuristics, right?  Like it understands if you call require with a string literal and a few other simple patterns such as "concat in require" (cf. https://webpack.github.io/docs/comparison.html).  If you use require in highly dynamic ways, neither Webpack nor any other tool can possibly even figure out what to bundle.  On the other hand, if Webpack can figure out what to bundle then I would have thought it could do dead code elimination even if you used CommonJS syntax, if ES6 syntax is OK.  But I need to study more!

Comment: Also, this blog post makes me wonder if there is already some kind of dead code elimination that I can get with Webpack 1 and uglify, but that tree shaking is something more that will eliminate stuff that is dead but would be missed by uglify: https://medium.com/@Rich_Harris/tree-shaking-versus-dead-code-elimination-d3765df85c80#.kh051gq8l

Comment: I'll give you a simple example to show you why ES6 syntax can tree-shake and why CommonJS syntax cannot. Since it's hard to show you code in the comment, I created a JSBin http://jsbin.com/metuga/edit?js,console. BTW, note that not all ES6 importing can do tree-shaking. See the JSBin for more comments.

Comment: In your JSBin, you don't give a CommonJS version of your tree-shakable ES6 import example, but it would be tree-shakable too; the tree-shaker would just have to be slightly more intelligent.  Namely, it would have to understand dot syntax.  That would be a good thing to teach it even in an all-ES6 world since it's pretty common to use dot syntax instead of named imports in braces even when using ES6 import.

Comment: In "named imports in braces" case, there is no way of invoking functions that are not present in-between braces. That's why it's tree-shakeable. With the dot-notation, you can tell which functions are used, but you cannot tell which functions are not used (because you can invoke functions other than dot-notation way; e.g. someModule[prefix + randomNumber]()). That's why it's not tree-shakeable. Does that make sense @gmr?

Comment: Yes. I think we are talking past each other a little.  I was saying that using the dot notation doesn't make it impossible to do tree shaking, and you are rightly pointing out that the static analysis is more complicated (you have to look at the whole file, not just one line).